# Invalid file path, but only if I build the file name with a field

Tags: java, file, field, filenotfoundexception

The following gives me a `FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path`

```
String fileName = "folder/file" + "." + this.ext;
try {
  File file = new File(fileName);
} catch(Exception e){
}
```

Where this.ext has previously been set to `"txt"`

After playing around, I find that this works perfectly fine.

```
String ext = "txt";
String fileName = "folder/file" + "." + ext;
try {
  File file = new File(fileName);
} catch(Exception e){
}
```

Why can't I use a field?

Comment: Can you paste the class whole code?

Comment: You should use a `Path` instance not a `String` to represent a directory path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't use a field i.e. `this.ext`. If you put a debug point at the following line, you will find that `this.ext` is not set to `"txt"`

```
String fileName = "folder/file" + "." + this.ext;
```

If you are not comfortable with a debugger, just put the following line before the above line and you will be able to find the problem:

```
System.out.println("this.ext="+this.ext);
```

Comment: Found it in the debugger. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After looking in a debugger, looks like my field had the value "\0\0\0\0\0txt" (ie the NUL ascii char).

Java sees "\0" as an empty string so my println statements weren't showing me the problem.

Must've been the first time I've needed to use a debugger over 4 years of uni!

Comment: Java does not consider the null character \0 'empty'. (C treats it as a string terminator, and C++ does the same for C-style strings, but  not std::string and std::wstring.) Java outputs it like any other (encodable) character. But if you were outputting to any kind of display, terminal or console, _those_ don't display anything for null.